# Initiale Fragment in bottom Navigation has duplicated [ANDROID STUDIO]

Tags: android, android-fragments, duplicates

I make an application android for a school project  , and actually i have a problem.

I have create 2 activity (MainActivity and BottomNavActivity), and I try to navigate between them, but the "fragment" home page in my navigation Remain undefined.
I found this tutorial in order to navigate between the fragments
and I added events) :

https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711

But, now, I can navigate between my "fragments" BUT my initial "fragment" (the one that appears first when launching the activity), remains, and therefore when changing fragments, it is duplicated.

[Here is a video of my problem](https://youtu.be/VxNZE0mJvXk)

**My Infos.class**

```
public class Infos extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityInfosBinding binding;

    //I create my variable
    final Fragment frag2 = new ProduitsFragment();
    final Fragment frag1 = new EntrepriseFragment();
    final Fragment frag3 = new CGUFragment();
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment active = frag1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityInfosBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_entreprise, R.id.navigation_produits, R.id.navigation_CGU)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_infos);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);


        //I add my differents fragments
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_infos, frag3).hide(frag3).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_infos,frag1).hide(frag1).commit();

        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull @NotNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    //My first fragment
                    case R.id.navigation_entreprise:
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(frag1).commit();
                        active = frag1;
                        return true;

                        //My second fragment (default in video)
                    case R.id.navigation_CGU:
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(frag3).commit();
                        active = frag3;
                        return true;                        
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**And my mobile_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/navigation_CGU"> //I try to change this, but nothing. This fragment is duplicated.

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_entreprise"
        android:name="fr.romaindrouhot.aurelinfo.ui.home.EntrepriseFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_entreprise"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_entreprise" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_produits"
        android:name="fr.romaindrouhot.aurelinfo.ui.home.ProduitsFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_produits"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_produits" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_CGU"
        android:name="fr.romaindrouhot.aurelinfo.ui.home.CGUFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_CGU"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_cgu" />
</navigation>
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Okay sée that under that post

Comment: Hi, have you tried to remove all the code below your comment `//I add my differents fragments`? Usually, the navigation component deals with the fragments transactions

Answer (score 0):

yes, here is my activity_infos.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_infos"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My fragment_cgu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My fragment_entreprise.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.EntrepriseFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_entreprise"
    android:background="@drawable/logonoiretblanc">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/entreprise_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/entreprise_title"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/informations"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_gerant"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/gerant_title"
                android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_green"
                android:textSize="@dimen/gerant_title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gerant"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/gerant"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/gerant"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_gerant"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/espace_entre_title_text"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_localisation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/localisation_title"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_green"
                android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:textSize="@dimen/gerant_title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gerant"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/espace_entre_text_title"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/localisation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/localisation"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/gerant"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_contact"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/espace_entre_title_text"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_activite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/title_activite"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_green"
                android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:textSize="@dimen/gerant_title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/localisation"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/espace_entre_text_title"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/activite"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/gerant"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_activite"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/espace_entre_title_text"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_contact"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/title_contact"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_green"
                android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:textSize="@dimen/gerant_title"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/espace_entre_text_title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activite"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/contact_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/contact"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/gerant"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_contact"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/espace_entre_title_text"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment section, the Navigation Component deals itself with the transactions between the fragments.

Here some tips to set up your BottomNavigation bar, hope it will help you.

First of all your `mobile_navigation.xml` and fragment XML seems to be good.

I could fix a bit your `activity_infos.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_infos"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="Odp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ...
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

- Update your Left/Right constraint with Start/End [here is why](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)
- Add a constraint between the bottom of the `id/nav_host_fragment_activity_infos` and the `id/nav_view`, just to be sure the fragment never be hidden by the navbar. It is optional.

Then, your activity could be updated without the `FrragmentManager`:

```
public class Infos extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityInfosBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // When you are using an activity you can directly use this
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_infos);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top-level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_entreprise, R.id.navigation_produits, R.id.navigation_CGU)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_infos);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);

    }
}
```

I found this [tutorial](https://learntodroid.com/how-to-use-the-jetpack-navigation-component-with-bottom-navigation/), it explains step by step, and it may provide more info than my "tips".

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for the answer, except that the problem is that one of my "item" has a function that launches a specific Activity (because I had a problem putting a ListView in a "fragment", of course. there, it's just my fragments that open (which is ok), but my activity no longer works?

Comment: If I understand well, you want to display a list of items into a fragment among these three tabs? Have you tried to implement [Recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) instead of ListView?

Comment: I just tested with a tutorial, but same problem as my ListView, I have an error with the setAdapter. That's why I went through another activity.

Comment: What kind of error do you have? That's weird because ListView and RecyclerView work well into fragment too

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
` 
for my recycler view 

And my listView : 

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
`

Comment: Is your databinding correct? How do you implement it in your fragment?

Answer (score 0):

**Can you please try replacing this with your `activity_infos.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_infos"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I replace, but nothing change... I have first fragment above my other fragment when i change...